# Выбор чисел Фибоначчи

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sqlite3, числа-фибоначчи

Задача не практическая. Хочется оценить, какими подходами ее можно решить на SQL'ях разных диалектов (`PostgreSQL`, `SQLite3`, `MySQL`). И как сложно это решаемо.

**Задача**

Есть таблица с положительными числами `[0..N]`. Нужно вывести в порядке возрастания все числа из указанной таблицы, которые входят в [последовательность Фибоначчи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Генератор без использования таблиц для SQLite, postgresql:

```
WITH Recursive Q(Num,Prev) as(
   select 1,1
  union all
   select Q.Num+Q.Prev,Q.Num
     from Q
    where Q.Num<10000
)
select Num from Q
```

Если надо выбрать из них только те числа, что есть в некой таблице - то в итоговый select добавить join с этой таблицей для проверки наличия числа в ней.

Для MS SQL и Oracle - убрать из запроса выше фразу `Recursive`. Для Oracle дополнительно добавить `from DUAL` после `select 1,1`.

Для MySQL требуется опорная таблица с нужным количеством записей, содержимое этих записей значения не имеет:

```
select @tmp:=@Prev+@Num as Num, @Prev:=@Num, @Num:=@tmp
  from seqnum, (select @Prev:=1, @Num:=1) A
 order by Num
```

Это опять же генератор. Для проверки наличия в некой таблице - заключить в подзапрос и сделать join.

Comment: И еще раз сенкс! Вопрос пока "принимаю" без проверки, ибо праздник начался ))) Ну а потом обязательно поразбираюсь. Тема рекурсии для меня неведома, больше всего манит посмотреть EXPLAIN этого хозяйства. Всех благ в новом году!)))

Comment: Пару слов в защиту MySQL. В MySQL8/MariaDB10.2 тоже будет WITH RECURSIVE. Для 8-ки уже можно пощупать. Тут - http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/27.html - перевод одной из статей на эту тему как раз с примером поиска чисел Фибоначи. С наступающим!

Answer (score 1):

Отвечаю сам себе :) пока для `PostgreSQL`:

Решается в несколько этапов:

1) Поиск максимального значения в таблице

2) `CROSS JOIN` всей таблицы с результатом выборки от хранимой процедуры по соответствию

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fib(f INTEGER) 
RETURNS SETOF INTEGER
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
WITH RECURSIVE t(a,b) AS (
        VALUES(0,1)
    UNION ALL
        SELECT greatest(a,b), a + b AS a FROM t
        WHERE b < $1
   )
SELECT a FROM t;
$$;
```

где аргументом будет максимальное значение из таблицы

Для SQLite3 и MySQL ждем-c ... ) Хотя, чего греха таить, возможно и для PostgreSQL без хранимой процедуры.